# WPF: How to smooth out a ColorAnimation with the starting point as Transparent?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I'm animating the background of a button at the control template level, but since the initial background color is set to Transparent, I'm noticing a weird effect where the transition jumps from Transparent => some white/gray intermediate => my desired color.

Here is a gif showing the effect: [image]

**Button Style (XAML)**

```
 <Style x:Key="btn-style"
         TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="15,0,15,0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
          <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                           Value="True" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>

                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.125"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    From="Transparent"
                                    To="#ff0000">
                      <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"
                                         Exponent="2" />
                      </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </ColorAnimation>
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
              <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.125"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    From="#ff0000"
                                    To="Transparent">
                      <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"
                                         Exponent="2" />
                      </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </ColorAnimation>

                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiTrigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

**Things I've Tried**

- Setting the DesiredFrameRate="60" definitely makes it smoother, but the intermediate "Gray" flash is still present.
- Not specifying the EasingFunction has the same behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see some white because `Colors.Transparent` is defined as transparent white , i.e. `#00FFFFFF`.

You may animate to/from a fully transparent red:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                From="#00ff0000" To="#ffff0000"
                Duration="0:0:0.125">
    ...
</ColorAnimation>
```

Comment: This worked. This might prove to be annoying when working on a UI SDK where I wanted to re-use a control. If for example instead of going to a red color, I wanted to go to a blue color, I would need to find the blue-equivalent transparent. What would you suggest I do in that case?

Comment: You may animate the Opacity of a SolidColorBrush.

Comment: That had the same visual effect and is much more reusable. I can then reuse this style using BasedOn and TemplateBindings. Thanks a lot!